# call postback through update panel request

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, updatepanel

I am using the update panel triggered on timer tick event which executes following code
In the ShowPanel method I want to make visible another panel outside update panel. but it does not shown until after satisfying the condition the postback happens.
any body have solution?

```
    protected void timerT_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       if (condition)
        {
            ShowPanel();
        }
    }
```

Comment: do you mean that you want the panel to become visible after 1. condition = true and 2. post back is happening?

Comment: Yes this could be the solution, but postback is not the condition to show, currently it requires postback to show the panel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All I needed is to call the postback script as follows..

```
protected void timerT_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (condition)
    {
        string jv = "__doPostBack('__Page', 'MyCustomArgument');";
        ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "postback",jv, true);
        ShowPanel();
    }
}
```

[More described information is available here](http://www.dotnetspider.com/resources/1521-How-call-Postback-from-Javascript.aspx)